# Possible to revert back to old documents Sitefinity?

Tags: content-management-system, sitefinity

I have just started working on sitefinity and was replacing some documents. However I replaced the wrong document and published it.

I went into the version history for the document but when I click on the older version I cannot even open up the older file. The button is there but I cannot click on it.

I also tried reverting to an older version and then publishing but this also did not work.

There is no real code to paste so I would just like to know whether it is a bug with Sitefinity or whether it is even possible to go back to an older version of a replaced document.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the file - then it really replaces it and there is no way of reverting it back from the revision history.

Hopefully you have a backup of the DB (or the blob storage) and you might be able to restore it.

Comment: Thanks, yeah we do, it seems to be that the revision history only can save or restore the meta-data of the file like the title.

Comment: Correct, confirmed by Telerik here: https://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/bugs-issues-/replace-a-file-in-documents-files-and-there-is-no-revision-history-of-the-actual-file#vQS3m30BPU2_a6ahm1KhWg